# Selenium with headless chromedriver not able to scrape web data?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a simple program to scrape data from https://stats.nba.com. My code here works absolutely fine, as it is able to get the data from the website perfectly:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://stats.nba.com/teams/advanced/?sort=W&dir=-1')
scrape = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table')

for row in scrape.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
    #...more parsing code here
```

However, as soon as I add
`chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`, the entire code fails and I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`.

Why does this happen? I've looked everywhere and cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Edit: the problems seems to be that `d.page_source` gives different results for headless and non-headless. Does anyone know why there is a discrepancy?

Comment: Looks like you should check the contents of d.page_source and see what the problem is.

Comment: @Chris I just checked, and strangely, the headless output of d.page_source does not have the table I want; however, the non-headless output of d.page_source contains the table. Why would this discrepancy exist?

Comment: If there is no recaptcha or something similar it could be that the page renders differently for different viewports.

Comment: @borisdonchev How would I get around this?

Comment: Try adding something to change it like this for example: `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`

Comment: @borisdonchev Already tried that, no luck. I think I may have to use a different webdriver or maybe even a different website for the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:

I think I've found the solution. It appears that they have a system that checks the user-agent of the browser and they don't allow headless chrome

so try to add this to your code:

```
# ...
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
# ...
```

This is the output that I receive from that:

```
scrape = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table')
for row in scrape.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

```
# <tr>
# <th></th>
# <th cf="" class="text" data-field="TEAM_NAME" ripple="" sort=""><br/>TEAM</th>
# <th cf="" data-dir="-1" data-field="GP" data-rank="" ripple="" sort="">GP</th>
# <th cf="" class="sorted asc" data-dir="-1" data-field="W" data-rank="" ripple="" sort="">W</th>
# <th cf="" data-dir="-1" data-field="L" data-rank="" ripple="" sort="">L</th>
```

Comment: Can you save the HTML content of the page and inspect it? There is a possibility that the content that you are receiving doesn't look like you expect it.

Comment: Yes, the HTML outputs are different for some reason when I run headless. I do not understand why

Comment: @blueblast I edited the answer. You can check if it works now (:

Comment: Fantastic! I've been stuck on this for days and finally found this soulution. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I've been stuck with this problem for an awkwardly long time and was on the verge of going insane.